# What kind of characteristics does the Great Tribulation have in LDS eschatology?

Tags: lds, eschatology, tribulation, signs-of-the-times

There is [this other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12251/what-is-the-lds-mormon-position-on-eschatology) with an answer that touches on the Great Tribulation as it is viewed in LDS eschatology, but I would like to ask more specifically about the situation on earth during the Great Tribulation:

1. What physical events do Mormons believe will happen before or during
   the Great Tribulation?
2. In what sense will it be a "Great Tribulation" - is this mostly
   symbolic or are there spiritual or physical (e.g. economical)
   reasons that warrant the label "Great Tribulation"?
3. Do Mormons have any official beliefs on how long the Great
   Tribulation is expected to last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I begin I'd like to restate from the other answer that the phrase "Great Tribulation" is not used in Mormon terminology/teachings and LDS teachings most closely align with post-tribulationist. That is Mormon's believe in a chronology that is along the lines of tribulation, second coming, Millenium, and then the last judgement. I will not go into great detail as most of this is covered in LDS manuals and covers several chapters, feel free to look at the referenced manuals if you want more detail.

> 1. What physical events do Mormons believe will happen before or during the Great Tribulation?

**Signs of the Second coming**<sup>1</sup>

- Wickedness, War, and Turmoil-*being fulfilled*
- The Restoration of the Gospel-*fulfilled*
- The Coming Forth of the Book of Mormon-*fulfilled*
- The Gospel Preached to All the World-*partly being fulfilled*
- The Coming of Elijah-*fulfilled*
- Lehi's Descendants Will Become a Great People-*partly being fulfilled*
- Building of the New Jerusalem
- Other signs (see the scripture references at the bottom of the chapter if you want the others)

**Second Coming**<sup>2</sup>

- Jesus will cleanse the earth-wicked will be destroyed
- He will judge His people
- He will usher in the Millenium
- He will complete the First Resurrection
- He will take His rightful place as King of heaven and earth

**Millenium**<sup>3</sup>

- Temple/Missionary work
- Satan bound
- Peace on earth
- Righteous government
- No death
- All things revealed
- A final struggle at the end of Millenium when Satan will be set free for a short time. Satan will gather his armies and they will be cast out forever.

**Final Judgement**<sup>4</sup>

- Judged by words, works, and thoughts
- Judged by records
- Inheriting a place in a Kingdom of Glory

> 2. In what sense will it be a "Great Tribulation" - is this mostly symbolic or are there spiritual or physical (e.g. economical) reasons that warrant the label "Great Tribulation"?

Because this isn't Mormon terminology it is hard to get a specific answer but based on the previous answer (above) there are spiritual and physical reasons that would warrant the label "Great Tribulation".

> 3. Do Mormons have any official beliefs on how long the Great Tribulation is expected to last?

No. We have to measure when the first sign of the Jesus' Second Coming is to the Second coming (no specific time period), plus 1,000 year Millenium, and then Final Judgement (again no specific time period). So at least 1,000 years.

<sub>1 https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-43-signs-of-the-second-coming?lang=eng</sub>

<sub>2 https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-44-the-second-coming-of-jesus-christ?lang=eng</sub>

<sub>3 https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-45-the-millennium?lang=eng</sub>

<sub>4 https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-46-the-final-judgment?lang=eng</sub>

Comment: that is interesting. Thank you @depperm. I noticed that the (linked) "Signs of the Second Coming" article refers to the "wars and rumours of wars" (Jesus' statement in Matthew 24:6–7) as part of the signs. What are the earliest wars that you consider as having been part of this sign?

Comment: The earliest war I consider part of it is the war after Christ left the earth, I don't know specifically when/what that is but it was a war and wars continue to happen

Comment: thanks @depperm, so the LDS view is that the signs of the second coming include all the wars since Christ left the earth? Is the LDS view that we have been in the "tribulation" phase since then or is the "tribulation" phase specific to our time period?

Comment: That is my personal view and the only official LDS view is `Nations are constantly at war` and that the prophecy is being fulfilled. I applied the prophecy to the time period after Christ's first coming and that includes our time period

Comment: I know this is an old question. But reading that last point, about how long the great tribulation will last, your answer concludes with "So at least 1,000 years.". Are you saying that the great tribulation would last at least 1000 years?

Comment: @user100487 'Great Tribulation' isn't a LDS theology so this is hard to define/answer. If you include everything I listed (signs, 2nd coming, millennium, judgment) it will be at least 1000 years since the millennium is 1000 years and the other periods don't specify how long they will take.